# How do I correctly post a file from an iPhone to a node.js server that is using node-formidable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, node.js, http-headers

**Update**: this has been fixed in the phonegap github repository on May 16th, 2011.

---

I have the following Objective-C code:

```
NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:photoPath];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo-file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", " my-photo.jpg"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:photoData];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", body.length] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Length"];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:appDelegate];

[photoData release];
[body release];
[request release];
```

I'm trying to post an image from an iPhone to a node.js server that is using node-formidable. The server is already working fine with images posted from a browser, but when I try to post from my iPhone I get the following error:

> Error: MultipartParser.end(): stream
>   ended unexpectedly at
>   MultipartParser.end
>   (/formidable/1.0.0/package/lib/formidable/multipart_parser.js:301:12)
>   at IncomingMessage.anonymous
>   (formidable/1.0.0/package/lib/formidable/incoming_form.js:80:30)
>   at IncomingMessage.emit
>   (events.js:61:17) at
>   HTTPParser.onMessageComplete
>   (http.js:132:23) at Socket.ondata
>   (http.js:1001:22) at
>   Socket._onReadable (net.js:677:27) at
>   IOWatcher.onReadable as callback
>   (net.js:177:10)

The **image is saved correctly on the server's temp folder**, but **it's node-formidable the one that throws an error** when trying to parse the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, formidable is quite picky with the end boundary.  Try this:

```
 NSMutableData* body = [NSMutableData data];    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", imageName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", @"image/jpeg"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:body];
```

Comment: thanks, somebody has just committed that patch to the phonegap repository.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly the problem is. I suggest that you install a tool that can show you what the differences are between those two requests when you upload image from browser and your app. The most famous tool is http://www.wireshark.org/.
Or some unfree tools, such as httpscoop (http://www.tuffcode.com/download.html, 14 days trial). I personally like both of them.

Once you find the difference, you can adjust your app code to make it send exactly the same request, which will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that Wireshark said I was sending a malformed HTTP packet, so I'm now using ASIHTTPRequest and it's working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`[request release];`

I would guess that your cleaning up the request object before it has send all the data. This would explain the unexpected stream exit.

Comment: I forgot to mention on my original post that the image is saved correctly on the server's temp folder, but it's node-formidable the one that throws an error when trying to parse the form.